# which is the standard screen resolution for windows mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, screen

I am developing the smart device application. There are different screen resolution for different window mobile devices. I want to know that which is the standard screen resolution for windows mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default controls scale pretty well across resolutions.  I've created forms in Visual Studio and deployed to multiple resolutions without any modifications.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard.

Many possibilities exist and the recent devices usually have 800x480. Others have: 640x480, 320x240, 320x320, 400x240, etc.